# Copy file - for loop python

Tags: python, loops, copy

Good afternoon,

I have some code here that is meant to copy about 200 csv's from the source folder into destination folders based on the "sector" that they belong to.  The sector that they belong to is identified via the "symbolslist" which contains csvs with a list of tickers. The code works for the *most* part except that it is taking the list of tickers in the final csv in symbols list and copying all those CSV's into all the destination folders.  Basically I need to somehow combined the first for loop with the 3 for loops below it but am having a hard time doing that. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

```
import os,sys,shutil
import glob 
import pandas as pd

source_dir =  'C:\TS'
dest_dir = 'C:\TS\Combined\Groups\Cross Asset Class'
#dest_dir = 'C:\TS\Combined\copytest'
base = 'C:\TS\Combined\Groups'

dest_dirlist = (base +'/Cross Asset Class', base+'/Bonds', base + '/Commodities', \
        base + '/Countries', base + '/Currencies', base + '/Industry Sectors', base + '/Segments and Styles', \
        base + '/Us Sectors', base + '\Volatilities')
print(dest_dirlist)

symbolslist = (base+'/Cross Asset Class.csv', base+'/Bonds.csv',base+'/Commodities.csv' \
                 ,base+'/Currencies.csv', base+'/Industry Sectors.csv', base+'/Segments and Styles.csv', \
                  base+'/US Sectors.csv')


for file in symbolslist:
    print(file)
    df_symbolslist = pd.read_csv(file)
    print(df_symbolslist)


for ticker_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.csv*')):
    for ticker in df_symbolslist['Ticker']:
        print(ticker)
        if ticker in ticker_file:
            for path in dest_dirlist:
                shutil.copy(ticker_file, path)
                print(ticker + ' File Copied')
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `df_symbolslist = pd.read_csv(file)` keeps overwritting `df_symobolslist`. You only process the last one. I am puzzled by the format here... what do the symbolslist csv's look like? How do they encode sector and symbols?

Comment: This is what the symbollist csv's look like: http://prntscr.com/en97is

Comment: This is what the csvs to copy look like.  http://prntscr.com/en98d2

Comment: The name of the symbolist csv is the sector group.  and the individual tickers within the csv are the sector constituents.

Comment: Can you take those screenshots and convert them to text and post here? That makes it more convenient for others to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem properly I think you should follow a slightly different approach. You can create a `dict` that maps tickers to the list of asset classes it belongs to. Then you that map to copy files. I don't think pandas helps here - you can build the map row by row using the standard csv module.

I haven't tested this code because I don't have a proper data set, but consider doing this:

```
import os,sys,shutil
import glob 
import csv
import collections

source_dir =  r'C:\TS'
dest_dir = r'C:\TS\Combined\Groups\Cross Asset Class'
#dest_dir = r'C:\TS\Combined\copytest'
base = r'C:\TS\Combined\Groups'

# asset classes of interest
asset_classes = ('Cross Asset Class', 'Bonds', 'Commodities',
    'Countries', 'Currencies', 'Industry Sectors', 'Segments and Styles',
    'Us Sectors', 'Volatilities')

# asset class directories indexed by class
dest_dir_index = {asset_class.upper():os.path.join(base, asset_class)
    for asset_class in asset_classes}
print(dest_dir_index)

# make sure destination dirs exist
for dir_name in dest_dir_index.values():
    if not os.path.isdir(dir_name):
        os.mkdir(dir_name)

# dict that creates key:[classes...] item when first accessed, used to keep
# list of asset classes for each ticker symbol.
ticker_to_class_index = collections.defaultdict(list)

for asset_class in asset_classes:
    symbolcsv = "{}.csv".format(os.path.join(base, asset_class))
    print(symbolcsv)
    with open(symbolcsv, newline='') as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        next(fp) # skip header
        for sectors, ticker in reader:
            ticker_to_class_index[ticker.upper()].append(asset_class)

# split ticker out of csv filenames and copy file to all asset classes
# mapped for that ticker.
for ticker_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.csv*')):
    ticker = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ticker_file)).upper()
    print(ticker)
    for asset_class in ticker_to_class_map[ticker.upper()]:
        dest_dir = dest_dir_index[asset_class]
        shutil.copy(ticker_file, dest_dir)
        print("{} copied to {}".format(ticker_file, dest_dir))
```

Comment: Thank you very much tdelaney.  Let me give it a shot.  Also here is a dropbox link to what my csvs look like.https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqbt3pa6qiz70vg/Cross%20Asset%20Class.csv?dl=0

Comment: And he is the type of file I am trying to copy. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vusdpn8oizcda82/XLY.csv?dl=0

Comment: Gave it a shot however it doesn't seem to like the "upper" in line 49 or 51.  Giving me a tuple error: ticker = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ticker_file)).upper()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'